# Ricci-flat metrics on Cotangent bundles in adapted complex structure

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, smooth-manifolds, fa.functional-analysis

greetings,

Let $(M,g)$ be a compact Riemannian manifold. On some neighbourhood $X$ of the zero section in the cotangent bundle $T^{*}L$ we have a complex structure $J$ and a Kähler form $\omega$ s.t. $(X,\omega)$ is a Kähler manifold. My question is: are there any examples known where such a construction does not admit a Ricci-flat Kähler metric i.e. where one cannot find a different Kähler metric which is Ricci-flat (maybe in the same cohomology or not)? I would be very thankfull for answers.

best regards
dominik

Comment: does anyone have an idea ?


Comment: anyone with an idea ???

Comment: Try looking at this paper of Stenzel: 

http://www.math.osu.edu/~stenzel.3/research/publications/ricci-flat.pdf



Comment: and also this one of Calabi:

http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/ASENS/ASENS_1979_4_12_2/ASENS_1979_4_12_2_269_0/ASENS_1979_4_12_2_269_0.pdf



Comment: The answer to your question could be probably found in these papers. I didn't take the time to look. My guess is that it almost certainly does *not* always work.

Comment: You need to clarify and provide more information.  For example, is $L$ the same as $M$?  Also, what is the role of the metric $g$?  Do you require some relation between $g$ and the Kähler metric or the complex structure $J$?  If not, why mention $g$ at all?  It appears that your question is just whether or not, for a given compact manifold $M$, some open neighborhood $X$ of the zero section in its cotangent bundle admits *some* Ricci-flat Kahler metric.  Would you be satisfied with an answer to this question?  The answer is 'yes' if $M$ is parallelizable, via an application of Cartan-Kähler.